# How can I check the mysql connection for a user/password using batch/shell script

Tags: mysql, batch-file, mysql-error-1045

How can I check the mysql connection for a user/password using batch/shell script?

I've user name and password, and I need to authenticate whether they are correct or not, but how?

I tried this way:

1. I've created a batch file "run.bat" with "mysql -u User--password=UserPassword < commands.sql"
2. "commands.sql" file contains "\q"
3. When I run the file "run.bat" the output is nothing when User/Password are correct and "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ... " when User/Password are incorrect. Now can we capture this output, and decide whether the connection is successful or not, if yes how?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution as below:

```
@echo OFF
echo \q | mysql -u User --password=UserPassword 2>nul

if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" (
  echo CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL
) else (
  echo CONNECTION FAILED
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the return status of `mysql`. It is stored in the `ERRORLEVEL` enviroment variable:

```
mysql -u User--password=UserPassword < commands.sql
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" (
  echo OK
) else (
  echo FAIL
)
```

If you are lucky, `mysql.exe` even returns a specific status for "logon failed" that you can react on. Most applications return 0 on success and something != 0 on failure. Use `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` right after a command to find out the current value.

A more advanced approach would be to capture and evaluate the STDERR stream of the application. This, however, would be material for a different question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a ".my.cnf" file

I do this, although id strongly recommend against using your mysql root login

```
[root@daaorc900c ~]# cat ./.my.cnf 
[client]
user=monitoruser
password=whatismonitor
[root@daaorc900c ~]#
```

Looks like you might be one windows so here is the doc for the "options files" in widnows

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Comment: Windows, my friend, Windows. ;-)

Comment: Ya ya ya... I added the windows option file doc for Windows :-/

Comment: BTW, just in case you think that - the downvote is not mine. I'm *very* reluctant with downvotes anyway.

Comment: Tomalak, no worries.

Machaa, the mysql "client" will look for "option" files in given locations and if its found you can pass arguments to mysql via them, i have a bash script that connects and dumps a database and I use the "user" and "password" options for the "[client]" to pass the proper username and password to the mysql client.